# sql with single quotes for parameter in where clause

Tags: sql, parameters, quotes

I have below sql where I am trying to pass name parameter to sql, how can i append, I am getting syntax errors..

I have to @name in place of steeve

```
if @name not null BEGIN
        set @sql = @sql + ' AND name=''steeve''';
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if @name is not null then
BEGIN
    set @sql = @sql + ' AND name=''' + @name + '''';
END
```